# How to convert nested group in Excel from SAP report painter export into tabular form?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-erp

SAP report painter exports a n-dimensional table in excel as a nested group format (columns A:B). I need to get this onto tabular form (columns D:I) as a summarized table. Ideally I would get a direct data feed onto a summarized table, but that solution is quite far ahead.

Attached photo is a modified snippet for illustration purposes.[image: SAP report painter export and summarized table]

I have written a loop in VBA which does it using a variant approach. For approximately 15.000 rows, this takes around 40 seconds for 7 dimensions. I am wondering if any built-in excel functions could do that more efficiently?

Comment: Pretty sure PowerQuery would ignore the grouping allowing you to create  your summary.